# fcm django, send message to single user having mutiple devices

Tags: python, django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to django. I want to know how can I send firebase cloud message to a single user having multiple devices using fcm django

Answer (score 0):

You neeed install [FCM Django](https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in you project. Then, you add `fcm-django` in you installed apps and after that insert you `server-api` FCM in FCM_Settings, file `settings.py`. Then, run a `makemigrations` and `migrate`. In you admin, you can create a FCM Device Object. Look this link, can [help](https://naveensingh.net/setting-up-platform-independent-push-notifications-with-django-and-firebase/) you